# CSS - Image doesn't appear on div's background

Tags: html, css, background-image, adobe-brackets

I got a pretty simple div, that for some reason the background doesn't want to appear:

```
       <div class="photo-div">

          <span class="my_name">My name</span>

       </div>
```

CSS:

```
.photo-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 680px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image: url(/images/background.jpg);

}
```

I've tried to edit the width and height, didn't help.

When I edit it to *background-color*, the background does appear.

I'm using Brackets while coding, and it has live preview using google chrome, and on the live preview, the background does appear as it should have, but when I open the page using Chrome alone, without Brackets, the background image doesn't appear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would check to ensure that your pathing to your file is correct. Made a fiddle with your code and to a web address and everything works properly - https://fiddle.jshell.net/t4ut7uLa/ - Check the inspector to ensure the file is loading

Comment: @MikeDiglio, yea I was mistaken about the path eventually, I had to to put `..` before the path starts, since the CSS file is in another directory, and I guess Brackets ignores that, since it's a project there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the image path you specified is correct

```css
.photo-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 680px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=32);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<div class="photo-div">
 <span class="my_name">My name</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I found the issue... since the CSS file is in another directory then the html file. I had to put `..` before the path, and it solved it.
Thanks!